# SQL error in CREATE TABLE using NUMBER identifier, Syntax error: unexpected 'NUMBER' (number)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm going through material for the Oracle Database SQL Certification exam.  The very first example given doesn't seem to work.

I'm currently using MySQLWorkbench, but have pasted the example into various online tools, too with the same result.  I've looked all over for why this would happen, but can find no answer.

```
CREATE TABLE SHIPS 
(
    SHIP_ID   NUMBER,  
    SHIP_NAME VARCHAR2(20),  
    CAPACITY  NUMBER,  
    LENGTH    NUMBER 
);
```

This won't compile, and has has the NUMBER and VARCHAR2 underlined in red.  On mouse over it says:

> Syntax Error: unexpected 'NUMBER' (number)

or:

> Syntax Error: unexpected 'VARCHAR2' (identifier)

Comment: Thanks Glahf.  MySqlWorkbench does syntax-checking for MySQL, but the provided DDL uses Oracle DDL syntax.  If you are connecting to a MySQL database, it seems reasonable that this would not compile, and that the editor is honestly trying to communicate that these syntax are not valid MySql DDL.  If connecting to Oracle, this should compile.  I would encourage you to try a different editor such as SQLDeveloper for working with Oracle.

Comment: Ok, I really appreciate the answer.  I'm trying to get a MacOS compatible editor, and I thought workbench would be good, since it's on the Oracle site.  I'll see if I can find another.

Comment: Since when does MySQL Workbench work with an Oracle database? For Oracle you can e.g. use [Oracle SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sql-developer.html)

Comment: Since when?  It was made by Oracle, why doesn't it work with an Oracle database?  I'm probably not the only person that assumed it would.

Comment: `length` is a SQL function in Oracle. It will let you create the table, but a column name that is also a function is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your query runs well. I tried it in DB Fiddle and it works. See by yourself in [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fd9fefe86899c9d009c8fcdbe64a0fce). You can use this web site to try out your Oracle queries.

Avoid using MySQL tools, since MySQL and Oracle are quite different and your examples won't work as you expect.

Comment: Will do, I'm almost done installing Oracle Database on a windows laptop after realizing that you can't use any of their databases on a mac.  Planning on using Oracle SQL Developer like alexgibbs mentioned.  Thanks.  Edit- Though I will use DB Fiddle too, especially if it becomes annoying to use two computers.